# xslt check if a variable is a decimal with digits after decimal seperator

Tags: xslt, integer, decimal, xslt-2.0

I want to show decimal inputs like 100.1, 100.0 in a different format from integer inputs like 100
I have used the following check for identifying decimals(The variable input is of numeric type)

```
 <xsl:when test="not(floor($input) = $input)">
```

It works for cases like 100.1 but it does not work for cases like 100.00, this would return false saying that this is not a decimal.
I have then tried to use

```
<xsl:when test="$input castable as xs:decimal">
```

This is would not work for integers like 100 as the check would return true.
I tried

```
<xsl:when test="$input instance of xs:decimal">
```

for which I am getting false for values like 100.50, not sure why.
Is there any other way I can solve this?

Comment: I regard this as *artificial* problem -- in mathematics 100.0 *is* an integer. You want to distinguish different *lexical* representations for an integer value in a different way -- this may not be possible, because often the lexical representation is lost long before the XPath expression is evaluated. For example, it is impossible to say whether the number `5` was originally entered as +5 or as 5. The same way, string(100.00) may or may not contain a dot -- in fact with Saxon 9.x it doesn't! Thus, unfortunately, the answer by @michael.hor257k produces `false()` when you want it to be `true()`

Comment: In fact *all* 11 XSLT processors that I work with, evaluate `string(100.00)` as `"100"`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to distinguish between 100 and 100.0, you cannot be in the numeric domain. Try perhaps:

```
<xsl:when test="contains($input, '.')">
```

or use regex.

Comment: The input is of numeric type, this gives an error "Required type of first argument of contains() is xs:string; supplied value has
  type xdt:numeric"

Comment: I am not sure what  `xdt:numeric` is. If you are using a schema-aware processor, and the input is defined as one of the numeric types (e.g. xs:decimal), then I don't think your processor can tell the difference between 100 and 100.0.

Comment: the variable is the result of a 'sum' operation and I think this is why the processor is treating it as a numeric type.

Comment: A `sum` operation cannot produce 100.0.

Comment: See my comment to the question to understand why this solution, which was obviously not even tested, doesn't produce the wanted result. BTW, to avoud the type error, you need to correct the expression to: `contains(string($input), '.'). **For the reader**: this solution is incorrect. Downvoted as such.

Comment: Well, this "incorrect", "untested", down-voted and bad-mouthed solution **does** produce the expected result - as demonstrated here: http://xsltransform.net/ncntCSm

Comment: No, the transformation pointed to by that link operates on *strings*, not on *numbers*. The question is all about numbers, not about strings. The correct test is: `for $num in (100, 100.0, 100.1) return {your-expression}`

Comment: Of course it operates on strings. The very first thing I said in my answer is that it cannot work on numbers.  The original question did not say the variable was defined as a number. This was added as a clarification after I posted my answer.

Comment: OK, now with the clarification, it is clear that this answer is incorrect and irrelevant for this question. It is "noise" that can confuse and distract the readers -- hence the warnings in my comment. Based on this, it would be good to delete this answer.

Comment: Irrelevant? It states clearly that it is impossible to distinguish between 100 and 100.0 if both are numbers. Everything else on this page written by Michael Kay and by yourself is merely restating the same thing.

Comment: Irrelevant, because the answer is not for the posted question.

Answer (score 2):

You really need to show how you have declared the type of the variable `$input` (or in the absence of a type declaration, how you have initialized its value). It makes a big difference.

Note that 100.5 as an XPath literal produces the xs:decimal value 100.5, but 100.5 held as the value of an untyped attribute node will be converted to an xs:double value approximately equal to 100.5.

In principle you can identify decimals that are not integers using

```
$x instance of xs:decimal and not($x instance of xs:integer)
```

but that assumes that you created the value as an `xs:decimal` or `xs:integer` in the first place; if you do `xs:decimal("100")` then you will probably[*] get an `xs:decimal` that is not an `xs:integer`.

[*] I say probably, because the spec requires it to be an xs:decimal, but it arguably permits it to be a subtype of xs:decimal, e.g. it could even return an instance of `xs:unsignedByte` here if it chose, or for that matter an instance of `saxon:integer-in-range-1-to-100`, so long as that is defined as a subtype of `xs:decimal`.]

Comment: Good answer. Another consideration is that 100 and 100.00 are two different *lexical* representations of the same value. Thus the evaluation of `string(100.00)` with Saxon 9.1J produces the string "100" -- a representation in which the decimal point and the zeroes following it are gone.

Comment: Dr. Kay, What were the reasons for the decision of the W3 WG that `100.00 instance of xs:decimal` is `true()`, but `100.00 instance of xs:integer` is `false()` ?

Comment: There were ferocious debates in the W3C XQuery group long before I joined it between advocates of "named typing" versus "structural typing". Named typing won, and I can't attempt to summarise the arguments. Named typing basically means values carry a type annotation that has to be explicitly allocated by casting/validation, whereas structural typing means you can infer the type from the content. With atomic values this leads to apparent nonsense like "3 instance of xs:positiveInteger" being false, which I've always thought was crazy.

Comment: I also think this is definitely crazy, Dr, Kay.  :(